# Start a process in background from adb shell without attaching the process to the terminal in Android

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have a simple problem.
I want to start/run a program file on an android phone using adb shell.
My Program is in /system/bin folder and has root privileges.

I want to run this program from my command prompt as `adb shell runme 3000000 > logs.txt` but it should not block the terminal, It should run in background.

I cannot use ***screen/disown/nohup*** for my problem as android doesn't have all this.
I tried
`adb shell "runme >logs.txt &"` but of no use.

When i issue command as
`adb shell`
`# runme 3000000 > logs.txt &`
It runs fine, when i exit the terminal/disconnect the device and then connect again to system.
Do `adb shell ps | grep runme` shows the process is still runnning in background.

Thanks

Comment: Wrap your adb shell command in some python script which spawns a new thread.

Comment: does adb shell has python in it?

Answer (score 0):

Busybox has `nohup` applet which works just fine in Android